# Laravel: Get query params of an generated URI

Tags: php, laravel, api

On the API I'm working on, a previous request generates a link that goes like this:

```
https://api.example.com/example/v1/individuals?$expand=emails%2Cphones&$skip=30
```

I need to get this "skip" param and send the data back to my backend, to process a request on the whole link plus the skip param, that changes along with the system.

Any tip on how to get this "skip" param?

Comment: explain this line in detail `On the API I'm working on, a previous request generates a link that goes like this:` is the api 3rd party?

Comment: Yes, a request is sent to a 3rd party and it responds with a JSON, with the mentioned URI as one of its elements.

Comment: are youn interested in using handler, what handler will do before sending the request it will provide you a RequestInterface class instance which should contain all the params, you can get which request has which parameters within that handler, which you can use as per your wish

Answer (score 0):

remove $ sign from query param and try `$value = request('skip')` to get skip value

Answer (score 0):

```php
// Your api controller
public function someMethod(Request $request)
{
    $request->query('skip', 10); // returns 30 for https://api.example.com/example/v1/individuals?expand=emails%2Cphones&skip=30 or 10 if skip is not set.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you received the url from 3rd API and you don't wanna change it, you can do the following:

```
    $urlFromApi = 'https://api.example.com/example/v1/individuals?$expand=emails%2Cphones&$skip=30';
//Remember to use single quote if you wanna paste string with '$' as a character with PHP.
    $url = urlencode($urlFromApi); 
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($parts["path"], $a);
    
    preg_match('/%24skip\%3D(\d+)/', $parts["path"], $matches);
    $skip = $matches[1];
    echo $skip;
```